# Strange: Read Only FS

Tags: linux, storage

I am using LFS-based OS onto a 4GB storage device. Everything was working fine for more than 6 months.
But suddenly, the storage device itself became **Read-Only**. No matter, what I do with this storage device. It always retains it's state with existing content.

e.g. If I install Ubuntu, Windows or any other OS on this storage device by completely formatting it. OS get installed successfully but when I reboot, newly installed OS get vanished and storage device shows it's original data.

If I boot from any LIVECD and mount the storage device. It get mounted but after creating/modifying some files/directories, changes get saved as long as device is mounted. But I loose the changes once I umount and mount it again.

How am I suppose to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: What are the manufacturer and model number of the storage device?

Comment: Snapshot features on a low level (in the controller or drive itself) used to exist and were designed for lab PCs and the like, to reset them to a clean state, and if that mechanism suddenly started triggering, it would look somewhat like that. But it's unlikely you'd have such a rare beast without knowing it.